# MIPS Converting hex to decimal, writing to a file

Tags: assembly, mips

I've got a problem, that I can't manage with. I'm trying to convert A-F chars to its decimal equivalents by subtracting 55 from the read byte, then putting it into a buffer and finally, write to a file. When I subtract and store a byte like this:

```
addi $t2, $t2, -55
sb $t2, 0($t9)
```

I get a weird char in my output file, that I even cannot post here. Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing 55 from 'F' is 15. If you write the byte 15 to a text file, it will be interpreted in ASCII by any text file reader as a non-printable signal character known as "SI" or "shift in".

What you want is to print the **characters** '1' and '5', which are the bytes 49 and 53.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Then, how to convert i.e. 0xAB to decimal? Should I load it into a buffer statring from the last character and then multiply by 16? I have no idea how to do it

Comment: You would start from 'B', convert it to decimal. Then add 'A' converted to decimal multiplied by 16. At this point you would have an integer with 171 in it (in a register, in binary). From there, you want to convert that value to ASCII. You can do 171 modulo 10 => 1 then add 48 to obtain 49 which is the ASCII value for '1'. Divide by 10 to get 17, modulo 10 again to get 7, add 48 to get ASCII '7'. Continue until your integer value is 0. At that point, you have a reverse array of the decimal representation in ASCII. Print it backwards and you're done!